# Tensorflow: Why doesn't my TensorFlow model train faster while using more powerful hardware?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I've been having some performance issues with my Tensorflow models. The models are CSV-based and have datasets that range up to 5 million rows and 6-8GB of data. I've tried to put together a small example that illustrates my approach. Am I doing something fundamentally incorrect here?

I'm trying to use the Dataset API to load from TFRecord files and then use the Estimator API to train and evaluate.

I've included example code that loads TFrecord files that have 1 feature (projectedPoints) and a label (pickTier). The training dataset has ~80k records and the evaluation dataset has ~18k records. I can include more or less data if you need it, but the behavior seems pretty consistent with even a lot more data. In my example I'm specifying the built-in LinearClassifier Estimator class, but I get similar results with any that I use including custom ones.

[Here's a link to a GitHub repo](https://github.com/ptoner/example/blob/master/script.py) that has actual tfrecord files if that helps.

I'm unsure about how I'm using a few things. Is this the right way to load tabular data from a CSV file? Am I approaching this wrong with this kind of data? The reason I'm doing it is because I was having similar performance problems when I was using an input function that was backed by a pandas function instead of the Dataset API. I kind of get the idea now that it might not be providing very much, but I had gotten the sense from other posts on here that it might help with larger datasets.

For a long time I was developing and running these models on a Macbook Pro. This worked fine until I got to the part where training would take a while. Then I figured it was time to throw more hardware at it.

I built a machine with a 16-Core 3.4 ghz AMD Threadripper, 32GB of RAM, and a 1080 Ti. All of the models run slower. I don't understand why.

I've also fiddled with the allow_soft_placement setting. The primary effect seems to be that you can't run an example like this entirely on the GPU due to some operations not being supported. Does that make sense?

---

Example 1

CPU: 2.5GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 (2015 Macbook Pro)

Tensorflow: 1.9.0 from pip

Device: "/cpu:0"

Result: ~300-320 steps/sec

---

Example 2

CPU: 16-Core 3.4 ghz AMD Threadripper

Tensorflow: 1.9.0 from pip

Device: "/cpu:0"

Result: ~275 steps/sec. Now running on a 16 core CPU vs a 4 core one. It's slower. Shouldn't I expect a much higher number based on CPU power alone? It only seems to use 8-10% of the total CPU power at any given time. That doesn't seem right either.

---

Example 3

CPU: 16-Core 3.4 ghz AMD Threadripper

Tensorflow: 1.9.0 built from source with CUDA support

Device: "/cpu:0"

Result: ~240-250 steps/sec

I think this is still running on the CPU only, but it's already a little bit slower just having the GPU enabled. Including logs that show the GPU exists. But since I'm specifying to use the CPU explicity I thought that would win? Maybe not. GPU usage sits around 2-4% during this. CPU at the same 8-10% as before.

INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2018-07-31 09:00:55.444038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1392] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0
totalMemory: 10.91GiB freeMemory: 10.30GiB
2018-07-31 09:00:55.444058: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-31 09:00:55.607347: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-31 09:00:55.607374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:958]      0 
2018-07-31 09:00:55.607379: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N 
2018-07-31 09:00:55.607568: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9965 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

---

Example 4

CPU: 16-Core 3.4 ghz AMD Threadripper

Tensorflow: 1.9.0 built from source with CUDA support

Device: "/gpu:0"

Result: ~230-340 steps/sec

The GPU is enabled now and it's even slower. GPU usage still hovers around ~2-4% most of the time according to nvidia-smi.

Here is the actual code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator
from tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.linear import LinearClassifier
from tensorflow.python.training.ftrl import FtrlOptimizer
from tensorflow.python.training.session_run_hook import SessionRunHook, SessionRunArgs
from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks import SecondOrStepTimer

device_name = "/cpu:0"

def train():

    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


    with tf.device(device_name):

        train_input_fn = create_train_input_function(
            train_tf_records_filename="train.tfrecords",
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle_while_training=True,
            shuffle_buffer_size=1000,
            train_epochs=10000,
            device_name=device_name
        )


        eval_input_fn = create_eval_input_function(
            eval_tf_records_filename="eval.tfrecords",
            device_name=device_name
        )

        estimator = LinearClassifier(

            config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                save_checkpoints_secs=360,
                model_dir="model",
                session_config=tf.ConfigProto(
                    log_device_placement=False,
                    allow_soft_placement=False,
                )
            ),
            optimizer=FtrlOptimizer(
                learning_rate= 0.001,
                l1_regularization_strength= 0.001,
                l2_regularization_strength= 0.001
            ),

            feature_columns=[
                tf.feature_column.numeric_column("projectedPoints")
            ]
        )


        train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
            input_fn=train_input_fn,
            max_steps=100000000
        )

        eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
            input_fn=eval_input_fn,
            throttle_secs=1000,
            start_delay_secs=1000
        )

        tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)


def parser(serialized_example):
    features = {}

    features['pickTier'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    features['projectedPoints'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)


    parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features=features)


    label = parsed_example["pickTier"]

    # Remove label
    parsed_example.pop("pickTier", None)


    return parsed_example, label




def create_train_input_function(train_tf_records_filename=None, batch_size=None, shuffle_while_training=None, shuffle_buffer_size=None, train_epochs=None, device_name=None):

    def train_input_fn():

        # with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        filenames = [train_tf_records_filename]

        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, compression_type='GZIP')

        def the_parser(serialized_example):
            return parser(serialized_example)

        # Map the parser over dataset, and batch results by up to batch_size
        dataset = dataset.map(the_parser)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(train_epochs)

        if shuffle_while_training:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)


        dataset = dataset.apply(
            tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device(
                device_name
            )
        )

        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

        features, labels = iterator.get_next()

        return features, labels

    return train_input_fn


def create_eval_input_function(eval_tf_records_filename, device_name):

    def eval_input_fn():

        # with tf.device("/cpu:0"):

        filenames = [eval_tf_records_filename]
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, compression_type='GZIP')

        def the_parser(serialized_example):
            return parser(serialized_example)


        dataset = dataset.map(the_parser)
        dataset = dataset.batch(18814)

        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

        features, labels = iterator.get_next()

        return features, labels

    return eval_input_fn


train()
```

Comment: Just enabling GPU support will not make the code run on the GPU. The code you posted explicitly declares the device as `device_name = "/cpu:0"`. GPU usage at ~2% sounds like it is running your displays. Change the device name to `/gpu:0` and post the results.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Example 4 is the one where I explicity set it to /gpu:0.

Comment: How big is your network? Your `tf.data.Dataset.map` call doesn't have a `num_parallel_calls` value, so it won't multi-thread it. If that's where your choke-point is then the best architecture imaginable on the network processing side will make things any faster.